# How to fix this? "Invalid attempt to call CheckDataIsReady when reader is closed"

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I created a constructor method to execute sqldatareader to avoid retyping sqlconnection but there's an error when I use it:

```
public SqlDataReader ExecuteCommand(string cmdText, CommandType cmdType)
{
    SqlDataReader dr = null;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = cmdText;
        cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
        try
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Open();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            dr.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    return dr;
}
```

I try to use it but the error occurs:

```
SqlDataReader dr = ExecuteCommand("Select * from EmployeeInfo where Employeeid = 2", CommandType.Text);
textBox1.Text = dr[1].ToString();
```

The error is:

> Invalid attempt to call CheckDataIsReady when reader is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Just consider the steps of your program:

```
try
{
   if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
   {
      conn.Open();
      dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   }
}
```

First you correctly open the connection and execute the command - everything fine with that!

```
finally
{
   dr.Dispose();
   conn.Close();
}
```

Next your code hits the finally-block - you (attempt to) dispose of the reader and close the connection! Again nothing wrong with that.
Next comes your problem:

```
return dr;
...
textBox1.Text = dr[1].ToString();
```

You return a closed reader and then attempt to read from it - which results in the error you are recieving.
IMHO two possible solutions come to my mind:

1. return the reader without closing it (check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689263/what-is-the-use-advantage-of-using-commandbehavior-closeconnection-in-executerea))
2. cache the reader-result and return it (in your case the string for the textbox)