# Is this a correct way of returning a SqlDataReader from a function?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

Here's my function I use for convenience:

```
Function executeSQL(ByVal sqlConn As String, ByVal sql As String) As SqlDataReader

    Dim sdr As SqlDataReader

    Dim objConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(sqlConn)
    objConn.Open()
    
    Dim dbCommand As New SqlCommand(sql, objConn)
    dbCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
    
    sdr = dbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

    Return sdr
    
End Function
```

This is the way I read data from the database:

```
Dim rsTest As SqlDataReader = executeSQL(someConnectionString, "select item from item_table")
        
While rsTest.Read()
    'do stuff
End While
        
rsTest.Close()
```

Is this a problem since I'm not explicitly closing the SqlDataConnection? And if so, is there any way to close it while still using that function?

Comment: You might consider the use of `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689263/what-is-the-use-advantage-of-using-commandbehavior-closeconnection-in-executerea)

Comment: @DaleK I already am, please see this line: `sdr = dbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)` Is this enough though?

Comment: Read the linked post, they talk about it there.

Comment: Can't help but feel you might be fair better served by implementing the `Using` clause to handle your IDisposable objects (Such as SqlConnection etc)  These  convenience methods, quite often turn out to be less convenient and troublesome than you think.

Comment: As a side note SQL Server's 2008 version is out of support for a few years now. If you are using it you really should consider an upgrade.

Comment: Also, there's rarely a need now a days to use SqlDataReader directly when you have open-source free ORM packages such as Dapper or even Entity framework.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using the raw readers. But it looks a bit ugly with Connection being left behind. OP, i *guess* you could return a tuple of Connection / Reader, but usually you just get connection in one method and then create reader in another. I think it would be much more prudent

Answer (score 0):

Well, the REAL question is why return a reader?

that is about the most "low use" object you could return.

Why not return a data table?

In 99% of cases, you find returning a data table is:

More useful, no loops.

Can assign the data table to a listview, gridview, repeaters etc.

While you CAN assign a reader to the above objects, you LOSE the ablity to use all columns from that data source in the row data bound event.

To be clear: by feeding above such objects a data table, then the on-row data bound even has FULL use of the data source - including columns you do not display in the data aware control. So, you might check a tax rate, or "id" or some such, but NOT include and NOT display that column in the said data aware object.

the next issue?

Why not use a sql command object here?

The sql command object has:

```
 a data reader built in - so you don't need one.

 has a connection object - again you don't need a separate one

 allows use of parameter's if you wish (no sql injection).
```

And why pass a connection string? You going in 99% of cases have a database setup, and thus no need to pass a connection string. (however, I do suggest you make it optional, since in some cases, you might have to work with more then one database.

So, using a reader is a POOR choice here. It just is!

So, then these 3 routines will get you 99% of typical use cases in code.

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String, ByVal Optional strCon As String = "") As DataTable

    If strCon = "" Then
        strCon = My.Settings.TEST4
    End If

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            rstData.TableName = strSQL
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function

Public Function MyRstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand, ByVal Optional strCon As String = "") As DataTable

    If strCon = "" Then
        strCon = My.Settings.TEST4
    End If

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

So, now to fill a grid view, we do this:

say this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"    />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CssClass="btn" 
                    OnClick="cmdEdit_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So, now this to load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    GHotels.DataSource =
        MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")
    GHotels.DataBind()

End Sub
```

and we get this:

[image]

but, note the edit button and click event?

Want to bet that 9 out 10 times when we click on a row, we want to load + get that ONE data row? The answer of course is YES we do!!!

(what good is a data reader???).

Once again, better we used a data table object.

So, the click event for that gv can be this:

```
Protected Sub cmdEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer
    ' get hidden database PK id
    Dim pkID = GHotels.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")
    Debug.Print($"Row index = {gRow.RowIndex}")

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotelsA where ID = @ID")
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pkID
    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    Call fLoader(Me.EditRecord, rstData.Rows(0)) ' load up hidden div with data
    ' hide grid
    MyGrid.Visible = False
    EditRecord.Visible = True
    ViewState("rstData") = rstData

End Sub
```

So, we get the PK, get the row of data, call floader (a handy routine that automatic fills out the simple controls in that div. It is a general routine I use over and over. It not like you going to HAND code each time you need to fill out a bunch of controls on the web form by hand? Right???).

so, now we get this effect:

[image]

The point here????

We 9 out of 10 times NEED a data table, or data row. So, why return a reader?

And what about my save button code?

Again, a helper routine - it WILL be working againinst a data table.

So, my save button code in above is this:

```
Protected Sub cmdSave_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click

    Dim rstData As DataTable = ViewState("rstData")
    Call fWriterW(EditRecord, rstData.Rows(0))          ' send div to table row
    Call SaveTable(rstData, "tblHotelsA")               ' send table back to database

    LoadGrid()    ' refresh grid
    MyGrid.Visible = True           ' show grid now
    EditRecord.Visible = False      ' hide edit area

End Sub
```

Again the point?
Well, we write some "more" helper routines, and they ALSO will and should work against a data table, and not a reader.

So, looking at above?

Once I have a set of about 4-5 routines, then ALL edit and display and operation of data becomes a simple breeze in code.

Note again, be it loading? A data table was great.

be it save of data? A data table was great.

And you can always loop the data rows like this:

```
    For Each OneRow As DataRow In rstData.Rows

        Debug.Print("Hotel Name = " & OneRow("HotelName"))

    Next
```

But, as noted, you can get bi-direction here. (send values BACK to the database).

```
    For Each OneRow As DataRow In rstData.Rows

        OneRow("VistDate") = DateTime.Now

    Next
```

And now I can call a routine to send those changes back to the database.

```
 Call SaveTable(rstData, "tblHotelsA")
```

And again, over time, we cobbile up more and more helper routines.

So, save table code is this:

```
Sub SaveTable(rstData As DataTable, strTable As String)

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("select * FROM " & strTable, conn)
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daU As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
            conn.Open()
            da.Update(rstData)
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

So, again, all of these helper routines?

By the time you built a few of them - not many?

You find coding as easy as desktop - like old VB or even like ms-access.

So, build 2 helpers:

MyRst - this takes a simple sql string - returns table

MyRstP - this takes a sql command object - so you can write sql injection safe code.

But, both return a data table, not a data reader.

And the other bonus part?

Well, we wrapped the connection string in a using block - so they are closed and disposed correctly for you.